# Preg replace img without id

Tags: php, html, regex, image, preg-replace

I can't figure out how to do a preg_replace to remove all img tags except for ones that have an id field e.g

```
<img class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-captchac wpcf7-captcha-captcha-489" id="captcha-489-img" width="72" height="24" alt="captcha" src="http://mysolarpower.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/wpcf7_captcha/1081225180.png" />
```

Don't replace this

```
<img class="size-large wp-image-54 alignleft" style="width: 487px; height: 595px;" title="" alt="german solar pics copy" src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/_d_improd_/german-solar-pics-copy-1024x955_f_improf_562x595.png" width="562" height="595" data-mce-width="487" data-mce-height="595" />
```

Replace this

I have this regex preg_replace which removes all img tags:

```
$contentOut = preg_replace('/<img[^>]*>/', '', $content);
```

I just cant figure out how to exclude anything that has an id field as well.

Thanks

Comment: Other than regular expressions have you tried anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead like this:

```
/<img(?!.*?\sid="[^"]+")[^>]*>/
```

So your code will become:

```
$contentOut = preg_replace('/<img(?!.*?\sid="[^"]+")[^>]*>/','',$content);
```

Explanation:

```
  <img                     '<img'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    id="                     'id="'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^"]+                    any character except: '"' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^>]*                    any character except: '>' (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  >                        '>'
```

[`Live demo`](http://regex101.com/r/rQ6iN7)

Comment: Thanks! Really helpful explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using a **Negative Lookahead** if you must use regular expression for the job.

```
$content = preg_replace('/<img(?![^>]*id="[^"]*")[^>]*>/i', '', $content);
```

See [`Live demo`](http://regex101.com/r/cM5mJ5)

Consider using `DOM` in the future for jobs like this.

```
$content = <<<DATA
<img class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-captchac wpcf7-captcha-captcha-489" id="captcha-489-img" width="72" height="24" alt="captcha" src="http://mysolarpower.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/wpcf7_captcha/1081225180.png" />
<img class="size-large wp-image-54 alignleft" style="width: 487px; height: 595px;" title="" alt="german solar pics copy" src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/_d_improd_/german-solar-pics-copy-1024x955_f_improf_562x595.png" width="562" height="595" data-mce-width="487" data-mce-height="595">
<img src="http://foo.jpg" id>
DATA;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($content); // Load your HTML content

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$imgs = $xpath->query("//img[not(contains(@id, 'captcha'))]");

foreach ($imgs as $img) {
   $img->parentNode->removeChild($img);
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Output ( It replaces all `img` tags that do not contain `id` with `captcha` text )

```
<img class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-captchac wpcf7-captcha-captcha-489" id="captcha-489-img" width="72" height="24" alt="captcha" src="http://mysolarpower.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/wpcf7_captcha/1081225180.png">
```

See [`Working demo`](https://eval.in/82700)

Answer (score -1):

`[^id]<img [^>]*>` worked for me in my tests - thanks to RegexPal